# Line breaks not appearing in optimal location

Tags: line-breaking, microtype

For some reason, despite using the `microtype` package, I cannot fix some overfilling in a paragraph, as can be seen in the image below.

I would prefer a line break immediately after the open bracket of each function call. I have tried to solve this issue by placing zero-width spaces between the first argument of each function and the left bracket of each.

Optimally, I would like solutions that would also work with the `\lstinline` command.

[image: Example paragraph]

```
\subsubsection{Map Scanning and Information Analysis}
Before any route-finding can occur, the map on which the robot finds itself must be internalised. There are three functions which are used for this purpose: getChosenArea(\hspace{0pt}gameEnvironment, topLeft, bottomRight), getMapMax(\hspace{0pt}gameEnvironment, gameType=1) and getMapRadius(\hspace{0pt}gameEnvironment, radius). All each of these do is scan the area specified in the parameters, and return a \Map{} object.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: @samcarter, thanks for the comment. As you've surmised, I'm new to this Stack, so I apologise for incorrect formatting and the like. I'll have a go at rewriting my example, but as I am aware that such typographical glitches are often very specific, and that I am using a set of formatting instructions that are lengthy (from an outside source), I was unsure what would and wouldn't be relevant, especially as I am new to TeX/LaTeX.

Comment: You nicely summarised why having a MWE is so useful on tex.se: for example to replicate your problem one needs to know the width of your line. Without having access to your "formatting instructions that are lengthy" one would need to make many guesses and experiments even before one could start to try to solve your problem.

Comment: That said: if the nice answer below solved your problem, don't spend time to create a MWE, but if your are looking for additional answers, a MWE would certainly be helpful.

Comment: Long (pseudo)words and two-column format fight each other. If you don't want to break the long words, the only alternative is to have underfull lines.

Comment: @egreg I think you meant to reply to my comment on the question. I think one reason why underfull boxes is an issue for me now is that I changed over to use \lstinline, but this is now outside question scope I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this many non-grammatical words involved, it is easiest to just use a `sloppypar`, as shown in the 2nd instance of the subsubsection.

In the MWE, the `\leftskip` is merely to match the OP's *unspecified* margins.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\Map{\texttt{Map}}
\begin{document}
\leftskip1.5in\relax
\subsubsection{Map Scanning and Information Analysis}
Before any route-finding can occur, the map on which the robot finds itself must be internalised. There are three functions which are used for this purpose: getChosenArea(\hspace{0pt}gameEnvironment, topLeft, bottomRight), getMapMax(\hspace{0pt}gameEnvironment, gameType=1) and getMapRadius(\hspace{0pt}gameEnvironment, radius). All each of these do is scan the area specified in the parameters, and return a \Map{} object.

\subsubsection{Map Scanning and Information Analysis}
\begin{sloppypar}
Before any route-finding can occur, the map on which the robot finds itself must be internalised. There are three functions which are used for this purpose: getChosenArea(\hspace{0pt}gameEnvironment, topLeft, bottomRight), getMapMax(\hspace{0pt}gameEnvironment, gameType=1) and getMapRadius(\hspace{0pt}gameEnvironment, radius). All each of these do is scan the area specified in the parameters, and return a \Map{} object.
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using sloppypar results in a lot of underfull box warnings/errors. Is this an expected outcome of this use?

Comment: @L0neGamer I think so, though I am not the authority on the subject.